# Access Route params in constructor - Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have this code below from my old Laravel 4.x. How can I convert this into Laravel 5.1? I am wondering how can I access the route params in the constructor(or in a middleware) if I convert it to Laravel 5.1

thanks!

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter(function($route, $request)
    {
      $this->user     = Auth::user();
      $this->project  = $this->user->getProject( $route->parameter('projects') );
      $this->group    = $this->project->groups()->find( $route->parameter('groups') );
    });
}
```

Comment: try `$this->route('projects');`

Comment: Method [route] does not exist.

Comment: What does `$route->parameter('projects');` gives you?

Comment: I don't have that var $route

Comment: So what's that in `$this->project  = $this->user->getProject(` **$route->parameter('projects')** `);`?

Comment: That code is from Laravel 4.x, I need to know what is the equivalent of that in Laravel 5.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92709/discussion-between-dr-calix-and-marco-aurelio-deleu).

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone will be helped by this:

`$request->route('companies')`